# Avoid Foreigkey repeat in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model like this:

```
class UserAdress(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
     area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
```

In admin:

```
class UserAdressAdmin(models.Model):
     list_display = ['user','area']
```

Admin lists all area for users.:

```
user1         area1
user1         area2
user2         area1
user2         area2
```

Is there any way to show like this?

```
<a href='link to all user1 areas'>user 1</a>
<a href='link to all user2 areas'>user 2</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: One solution could be if you make `user` `unique=True` and change the `area` relation to `manytomany`. Then you have unique users in listing, having their areas in details. right?

Comment: @Ahsan, many thanks for help. But Im not authorized to chenge the model.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need to redefine the models and relations - maybe using some other relation type. So you can add something like that in your admin model(isn't it admin.ModelAdmin?):

```
class UserAddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def user_areas(self, obj):
        areas = Area.objects.filter(pk__in=UserAddress.objects.filter(user=obj.user).values("area__id"))
        return "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (
            reverse("reverse_to_areas"), obj.user.username)
    user_link.allow_tags = True

    list_display = ['user_areas','area']
```